# Error "can't create or remove files in install directory" when installing by source code in Python

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to setup my Python environment in cloud Linux. I copied the working folder "Artem's_strategy", which contains the source code **setup.py**, from local PC to the cloud LInux system. When trying to install **setup.py** I get the following error

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx Artem's_strategy]$ python3 setup.py install
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-2160.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).
```

In other thread I found solution in the form of using `--install-dir`, which brings following error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx~]$ /home/ec2-user/Artem\'s_strategy/setup.py --install-dir=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
: No such file or directory
```

Checking the folder we can see that **setup.py** exists in this folder:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx Artem's_strategy]$ ls -la
total 1480
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ec2-user ec2-user     354 Mar 17 15:51 setup.py
```

So your help with installing from source code **setup.py** would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Comment: Python version 3.7.6

Comment: Try my answer, it might just be a case of a different directory.

Answer (score 15):

You should try this:

```
python setup.py install --user || exit 1
```

source: https://github.com/hughperkins/pytorch/issues/8

Comment: python setup.py install --user was enough and worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you go into a terminal and execute:

`python3 -m site`

It should give you a response similar to the following:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/tyler',
    '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
    '/home/tyler/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/tyler/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/tyler/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Using this, you can determine the directory in which your `site-packages` are stored and use the

`--install-dir`

parameter to install it there. Hope this helps!

Comment: `> [ec2-user@ip-xxx Artem's_strategy]$ setup.py --install-dir=/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
-bash: setup.py: command not found`

Comment: Try: `python3 setup.py --install-dir=/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages -bash: setup.py: command not found'`

Comment: The respond is `usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --install-dir not recognized`

Comment: Oh, you just need to type `install` after `setup.py` but before `--install-dir`

Comment: Same problem appears: 
`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-2-41 strategy]$ python3 setup.py install --install-dir=/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --install-dir not recognized`

Comment: Have you tried just doing `python3 setup.py install` ?

Comment: Of course (it is in the body of main question). I eventually created Ubuntu system in cloud and installed everything on it. Works fine. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

After finding where your site-packages are installed, use --prefix=location in your command.

```
python3 setup.py install prefix=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages
```

Comment: python setup.py install --prefix=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages is worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I followed Tylerr's answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/60727896/13916894 but instead of `--install-dir` used `--prefix` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if it will work but I had a similar issue with Flask Restful on my WSL

What worked for me was running the whole setup from https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html after having full permissions with

```
sudo su
```